# Pandas Pivot Table Keeps Returning False Instead of 0

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, aggregate-functions, pivot-table

I am making a pivot table using pandas. If I set `aggfunc=sum` or `aggfunc=count` on a column of boolean values, it works fine provided there's at least one `True` in the column. E.g. `[True, False, True, True, False]` would return 3. However, if all the values are `False`, then the pivot table outputs `False` instead of 0. No matter what, I can't get around it. The only way I can circumvent it is to define a function follows:

```
def f(x):
    mySum = sum(x)
    return "0" if mySum == 0 else mySum
```

and then set `aggfunc=lambda x: f(x)`. While that works visually, it still disturbs me that outputing a `string` is the only way I can get the 0 to stick. If I cast it as an `int`, or try to return 0.0, or do anything that's numeric at all, `False` is always the result.

Why is this, and how do I get the pivot table to actually give me 0 in this case (by only modifying the `aggfunc`, not the dataframe itself)?

Comment: Please post an example DataFrame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'count': [False] * 12, 'index': [0, 1] * 6, 'cols': ['a', 'b', 'c'] * 4})
print(df)
```

outputs

```
   cols  count  index
0     a  False      0
1     b  False      1
2     c  False      0
3     a  False      1
4     b  False      0
5     c  False      1
6     a  False      0
7     b  False      1
8     c  False      0
9     a  False      1
10    b  False      0
11    c  False      1
```

You can use `astype` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html)) to cast to `int` before pivoting.

```
res = df.pivot_table(values='count', aggfunc=np.sum, columns='cols', index='index').astype(int)
print(res)
```

outputs

```
cols   a  b  c
index         
0      0  0  0
1      0  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you, that does work. However, my program can't change the dataframe (for reasons I won't go into here). Suffice to say, my solution has to rely on aggfunc only. Do you know a way to do it without changing the dataframe?

Comment: @Elliptica Sure, just move the `astype` call to the result. Answer updated.